# Django template with External CSS ; using {%static%} for images in a division

Tags: python, css, django

I am using django for a web app and encountered a no image shown problem with the following code:

```
<div class="hexagon-in2" style="background:url(static/images/gallery/2.jpg)">
```

Please Help with this situation.

Comment: thats not how you include staticfiles in django read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: yes, i do use;
<img src="{% static 'images/templatemo_logo.jpg' %}" alt="Polygon Template" width="366" height="204">
but the question is about image within a 'style' tag. thats what confusing me. or is there any alternative for fixing a background image to a division in html file?

Comment: Why would it be any different in a style tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your `MEDIA_URL` in `settings.py`

```
<div class="hexagon-in2" style="background:url("{{ MEDIA_URL }}/images/gallery/2.jpg)">
```

// or `STATIC_URL` if you use static files for storing images and media